# Error when importing local csv file to python

Tags: python, csv, import

I tried to import `.csv` file from my computer to python, but both codes didn't work. What is wrong?

First try:

```
import csv
with open('chicago.csv') as chicago_data:
    csvReader = csv.reader(chicago_data)
    for row in csvReader:
        print(row)
```

Second try:

```
import csv
with open('chicago.csv') as chicago_data:
    csvReader = csv.reader(chicago_data, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvReader:
        print(row[0])
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - We care about code that can be copy/pasted and screenread - your links: no can do any of it  - please fix. Comments are to short to list all the reasoning behind that, visit the link to read up on it

Comment: What error message are you getting? and instead of adding image, kindly add code to question description.

Comment: No result came out instead of letting me put more code.

Comment: check the examples in the  [python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and the [python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code on my computer and I am able to print data from a CSV file I was working with. Without additional information (such as error code/message) or some output value, it is hard to answer what could be wrong with your code.

Possible issues:

- CSV file not placed in the same directory as the script

Comment: Yes. It works when I moved file to the right directory.                          with open('C:\\Users\\jasch\\chicago.csv') as chicago_data:   However, I have 3 csv files. How to open all? concat?

Comment: Depends on the type of information you have in the files and what you want to infer from the data.